# Couldn't get value from while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

as you see in this code i made a table by selecting models from table in my database..
however i posted the return of the select query to be like the primary column for this table and put it into the while loop so it keeps generating rows till the models which came with the select query be finished
now i got a a problem when i'm trying to get this models in a $_Post[''] supergloble it keeps send me only the last value it gets from the loop
my question is how to get each and every value from the this loop to use it in a single insert query in my DB?

and sorry for the bad English :S !!

```
<form class="form-signin" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="Post">
<?php
$models = mysql_query("SELECT `Model_Name` FROM `models` WHERE `Brand` = 20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($models))
    {
    echo '
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="mode[]" value="'.$row['Model_Name'].'"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sellout[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="shelfshare[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Shortage[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Inventory[]" value=""></td>
     </tr>

    ';
    }

    ?>

</form>
```

the inserting script

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
foreach($_POST['mode'] as $key => $mode){
$sellout = $_POST['sellout'][$key];
$shelfshare = $_POST['shelfshare'][$key];
$price = $_POST['price'][$key];
$shortage = $_POST['shortage'][$key];
$inventory = $_POST['inventory'][$key];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `smartdailyreport`(`SFO_Code`, `Model`, `Sell_Out`, `Shelf_Share`, `Price`, `Shortage`, `Inventory`, `Date`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['idd'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($mode)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($sellout)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($shelfshare)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($price)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($shortage)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($inventory)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: `$POST` might throw an error for undefined variable - better fix it: `$_POST`

Comment: also, put your insert query inside the `foreach` loop, otherwise you're just overwriting your values each time it iterates

Comment: Before you write **any** more SQL code, you must read up on [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). `mysql_query` is also being removed from PHP in future versions because it's so easy to abuse like this. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and makes it easier to write properly escaped queries.

Comment: about mysql_query i know it had been changed to mysqli_query but my webhost using old version of php so i have to use the old one :S

Answer (score 1):

Make the name of those inputs an array :

```
 <tr>
<td><div class="col3" align="center"><input type="text" name="mode[]" class="form-control" value="'.$row['Model_Name'].'"></div></td>
<td><div class="col3" align="center"><input type="text" name="sellout[]" class="form-control" value=""></div></td>
<td><div class="col3" align="center"><input type="text" name="shelfshare[]" class="form-control" value=""></div></td>
<td><div class="col3" align="center"><input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control" value=""></div></td>
<td><div class="col3" align="center"><input type="text" name="Shortage[]" class="form-control" value=""></div></td>
<td><div class="col3" align="center"><input type="text" name="Inventory[]" class="form-control" value=""></div></td>
 </tr>
```

Then when you process the form:

```
foreach($_POST['mode'] as $key=>$mode){
    $thisIsOne = $_POST['mode'][$key];
    $alsoThisOne = $_POST['sellout'][$key];
    etc...
}
```

Comment: it still not working and now it isn't sending any data to the insert script even the model 
        Skip a line and indent eight spaces.
        That's four spaces for the list
        and four to trigger the code block.

Comment: @MahmoudAhmed That's because this hasn't been changed/fixed `$mode = $POST['mode'][$key];` notice `$POST`? it needs be `$_POST`

Comment: ok i fixed it but for now i have got the model values into the DB but i didn't get the other values it keeps sent me nothing :S

Answer (score 0):

I'll put my comments into an answer for you...

You've got `$POST` as your `$mode` value, fix that up. (or remove it, `$mode` is already defined from the `foreach`)

Put your query **inside** your `foreach` loop, otherwise you just overwrite those variables each time you iterate, then insert the last one at the end

Put `mysql_error` into the `die` callback of `mysql_query` to show you an error if there is one (if you want to)

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
foreach($_POST['mode'] as $key => $mode){
    $sellout = $_POST['sellout'][$key];
    $shelfshare = $_POST['shelfshare'][$key];
    $price = $_POST['price'][$key];
    $shortage = $_POST['shortage'][$key];
    $inventory = $_POST['inventory'][$key];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `smartdailyreport`(`SFO_Code`, `Model`, `Sell_Out`, `Shelf_Share`, `Price`, `Shortage`, `Inventory`, `Date`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['idd'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($mode)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($sellout)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($shelfshare)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($price)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($shortage)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($inventory)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Lastly, use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql` as `mysql` has been deprecated for some time now. And also, use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or similar to [escape your POST variables and save you from SQL Injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: PDO is preferable to `mysqli` because of named placeholders. Even better is a proper ORM like [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html).

Comment: thanks man for your comments the only problem for me now is how to the dynamic values from the while loop now after i fix the problems i got the model in the DB but but i didn't get the other values so any suggestions ??